# Determine if key pressed is writing something - Javascript

Tags: javascript, keycode, keyup, onkeyup

I want to run an action only if the key pressed is writing something, so it ignores arrow keys, shift key or enter key etc.

I am using the following script, but I would like to find an alternative to Improve it.

```
$('body').on('keyup', 'input', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57 || e.keyCode >= 65 && e.keyCode <= 90 || e.keyCode >= 97 && e.keyCode <= 122) {
      // do something
  }
});
```

Comment: We need more context. Are you trying to detect when a user changes the text inside a text field?

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: the problem is my script include only the Number, Alphabet upper case and Alphabet lower case. @Kwright02 I want to run action only if input content change.

Comment: There is no alternative to that. You are already doing it the best possible way. Other way would be instead of checking for printable characters, you could check for non-printable characters. There isn't much difference at all.

Comment: you could look into events that are fired on textfields

Comment: @whitehathackersree i don't know if my script include all character types.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments:

> the problem is my script include only the Number, Alphabet upper case and Alphabet lower case.I want to run action only if input content change

In order to trigger an event when text changes in the input, you need to define a global variable holding the previous data of the input.

Then when a `keyup` event is fired, you can check whether the `input_data==new_input_data`, then do whatever you want.

```js
var input_data, new_input_data;
input_data = $("#myinput").val();
new_input_data="";
$('body').on('keyup', 'input', function(e) {
  new_input_data = $("#myinput").val();
  if(input_data!=new_input_data){
      alert("text changed");
      input_data = new_input_data;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="myinput" />
```

Comment: @MustaphaFersaoui Updated again please check. Use the Run code snippet and check again.

Comment: I don't know why the variables out of the function are not taken into account. that give undefined value

Comment: Could you please post your code at https://jsfiddle.net and share back the saved link so that I can help.

Comment: I think because I used it for tinyMCE and to call an input inside popup. thanks for your time